# ssl3 mailx and bounce

Tags: mailx

I have set some email server(postfix with tsl3) and i have reach the goal
to remove ssl2 from it,but thunderbird works perfect,mailx no.
I did

```
echo prova|mail -S smtp-use-starttls user@domain
```

and all mail are bounced

```
said: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
I use this configuration
master.cf

smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject
```

main.cf

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_sender_login_mismatch,
    reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
    reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
    reject

# TLS parameters
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/domain.local.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/slackware.domain.local.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/slackware.domain.local.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, MD5
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3
```

Thunderbird ok,but mailx no,i try

```
mail -S smtp-use-starttls
```

Of course mail is linked with ssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found

On main.cf

```
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
```

on master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject
```

Ssl3 and 2 disabled and mail received